# How can I force menu items to fit to column width?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I have a left sided menu like this:

```
    <table table-layout="fixed" width="800px">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td width="140px" overflow="hidden">
                 <div class="link-list">
                    <ul class="tablist">
                        <li> <a href="/url1/">Short</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="/url2/">MediumItem</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="/url3/">ThisIsALongWidthItem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>  
            <td>
                  the page main content here                                        
            </td>      
        </tr>   
    </table>
```

The CSS is like this:

```
.tablist 
{
list-style:none; 
height:2em;
padding:0; 
margin:0; 
border: none;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.tablist li 
{
float:left; 
margin-right:0.13em;     
}

.tablist li a 
{
display:block;
padding:0.5em 3em;    /*I'm trying to set this value*/
text-decoration:none;
border:0.06em solid #000;
border-bottom:0;
}
```

I want to make items to fill the whole width of the left column. when setting padding to small value, they  leave space at right side because items have different width. So I'm trying to set it to big value (hopping that it can fill the empty space) but they exceed the column margins and get mixed with the contents of the right side col.
How can I make it delimited to the column width??

Comment: Change `<table table-layout="fixed" width="800px">` to `<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:800px">` and `<td width="140px" overflow="hidden">` to `<td style="width:140px; overflow:hidden">`

Comment: thank u very much. I really missed this trick. It works, but the solution @Matt Steele provided is OK, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a max-width on the li to make sure it doesn't go further that it's parent container.

```
max-width: 100%;
```

I'm not sure if this is what you mean though. It would be best if you could set up a JSFiddle to mimic the problem.

It looks like you may be fighting an issue between using both the li and the a for width.

Answer (score 0):

Using the regular box model makes it difficult to account for padding and border, since they are being added to the declared width, and so you have to engage in calculations to subtract them from the width.
The best option is to go back to the original IE box model which includes the padding and the border in the width (so when you declare width 100% you know it is always 100%, inc. border and padding).
to do this use the following css ruleset:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this as well. Setting box-size: border box; is a great way to tame the box model. It only has support on IE8 and up though, so make sure you account for that with Modernizr if you need to support old IE.